# My Header over External Content

Tags: iframe, external

I can see this web site is somewhat over my head, but I'm having trouble finding an answer.

I want to put my header, with links to other pages, over external content. Here's why: My MLM gives me a replicated web site that they maintain. I want to add links to my blog, contact info, even meta tags to the site. I though I had it done by using an iframe. I have my content at the top, and the MLM site shows up in the iframe. (here is the link www.trivanijoanne.com) The problem is that the iframe doesn't resize when the external content changes, and it is confusing for the user to need to scroll up to see the page. Also, the pdf pages don't load inside the iframe.

I looked around online and see that iframes are a thing of the past. What should I be using to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

you could use PHP to get the page markup (possibly using cURL or fopen) and display it whilst putting your own content into the body section

(str_replace()

```
<body>
```

with

```
<body><div id='header'>my content</div>
```

)

and attach your own css stylesheet with

```
*{
position:relative;
top:-100px;
}
```

if you cant use PHP for some reason then this could also be done using javascript and iFrames